# Yii2 select widget multiselect with default text issue

Tags: php, yii2

Hi I am using Yii2 selectwidget::widget & html::dropdown() functionality
When ever, i enable multiple true,
Default text will not display.. functionality works fine.

```
1)Html::dropdownList(
    'companyName[]',
    [],
    Company::getCompanyList(),
    [
        'prompt'     => Yii::t('app', 'Select Distributor'),
        'multiple'   => true,
        'type'       => 'search',
        'id'         => 'companyName'
    ]
);
```

How can we resolve this?

Comment: what do you mean by default text are you talking about when editing a record? and what is `CompanySelectWidget` ? there isnt any select2 used here that you are referring to in your question

Comment: It means Place holder, like "select Distributor"